# automation login to a website does not lead to the same page without automation (selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to do some automation for a website using selenium and there is a login password to enter and when I automate the login it goes to one page, and when im not automating it goes to another(the right one)...the login info are identical and there is no explanation in the landing pages that will explain the behaviour...does anyone know if this means that the website added some security features that will detect automation?... I dont know even if its possible..will love to get help

this is what im doing:

```
driver.get("https://somewebsite")


val userNameTextFieldLocator: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username"))
userNameTextFieldLocator.sendKeys("vvv")


val passwordTextFieldLocator: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("password"))
passwordTextFieldLocator.sendKeys("vvvv")


val pinNumLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("pinnumber"))
pinNumLocator.sendKeys("vvvv")

val logginButton: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.className("login_button"))
logginButton.click()
```

Then I see this security popup:

[image]

then to continue I go:

```
val alert: Alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
    alert.accept()
```

Comment: Have you tryied open the website as annonymous? (ctrl + shift + n in crome)

Comment: can you please try logging into this page without using your personal Chrome account?

Answer (score 0):

before initialize the driver try to:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));

driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the header Text from the Window Popup or the New page.

Next have a if-else case , if you get the above mentioned error-- 
Refer to these

[Handle Securtiy Warning pop-up in FireFox with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320118/handle-securtiy-warning-pop-up-in-firefox-with-selenium-ide)

[How to Click a option in Security Warning dialog box using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345525/how-to-click-a-option-in-security-warning-dialog-box-using-selenium)

If not, do as usual.